# how to install gmp for php on macOS Sierra?

Tags: php, macos-sierra, gmp

So far this is what I have done:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp
```

`php -i | grep gmp` gives me this output:

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-gmp.ini
gmp
gmp support => enabled
```

Yet, `phpinfo` is not showing up the gmp module and on using `gmp_init` command in my code, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gmp_init()
```

Any clues to what am I missing here?

EDIT: Additionally:

`Loaded Configuration File` (in phpinfo) : `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini`.

But running 
`which php` gives me: `/usr/local/bin/php`.

and `php --ini` gives me: 
`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-gmp.ini`

Comment: how are you running `phpinfo()`, `php -S`?

Comment: phpinfo through the browser in a simple file:  <?php phpinfo(); ?>.

Comment: your web server (presumably apache) is probably configured to point to the disrtibution php. Make certain you load the libphp5.so that points to the homebrewed one.

Comment: Do you mean adding a line like this in httpdconf file: `LoadModule php_gmp_module /usr/local/Cellar/php70-gmp/7.0.19_10/gmp.so` - this I have already done and restarted the server a few times. The result listed above is after having made this change to httpdconf file.

Comment: in the phpinfo output, look for the ini files that are read.  See if they match the ones you get from the command line.